# CUDA/Thrust Image Processing

Tags: c++, image-processing, cuda, nvidia, thrust

I was unable to find any information about if the Thrust library could support matrix operations. Therefore, I was wondering if it were possible to use the Thrust library in Image processing? I would also like to see any examples.

Thanks for any responses.

Comment: You might check out cuBLAS. It doesn't use Thrust, but they could potentially play well together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thrust supports regualar [algebra operations](http://code.google.com/p/thrust/wiki/QuickStartGuide#Transformations) on matrices but if you are using mostly sparse matrices and need solver type operations take a look at [cusp](http://code.google.com/p/cusp-library/)

Answer (score 3):

For image processing, you may want the [NPP library](http://developer.nvidia.com/npp). Since you asked about matrix operations, you may want to take a look at CUBLAS and CUSPARSE, also available from nVidia, [here](http://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit-40).

As for actual Thrust integration of these libraries, many of us have been asking nVidia for that for ages. Roll your own wrapper is the way to go in this case.

That said, Thrust is fantastic for manipulating 1D signals.

Answer (score 2):

You can look and extend [OPENCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/OpenCV_GPU)
's Image libraries. They use NPP underlying and the code is BSD.